# Intellij downloads Gradle dependencies but cannot resolve symbols

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

When I try and use dependencies I have set out in my build.gradle Intellij cannot build the code and raises errors `java: cannot find symbol`. How can I get Intellij to recognise my dependencies?

PS: The lbrary is showing up in "External Libraries" and I am also having this issue with all my other dependencies.

In my build.gradle I have this:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
}
```

In my code I try and use this library:

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHTTPClient;
...
OkHTTPClient client = new OkHTTPClient();
```

errors raised on both lines.

EDIT from comment: Command line build fails with the same errors, I guess I wrongly blamed Intellij. How can I tell why the dependencies are not being downloaded? They are sitting in my build.gradle in dependencies just as I showed. They are also present when running `gradle dependencies` under compile, default, runtime, testCompile and testRuntime, but not archives. Is that where the issue lies?

EDIT2: Ouput of `gradle dependencies`:

```
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
\--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0
     \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
\--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0
     \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1

runtime - Classpath for running the compiled main classes.
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
\--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0
     \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1

testCompile - Classpath for compiling the test sources.
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1
\--- junit:junit:4.11
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testRuntime - Classpath for running the compiled test classes.
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.1
\--- junit:junit:4.11
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.82 secs
```

Comment: Double-check that the libraries could actually be resolved, and that the Gradle command-line build succeeds.

Comment: Command line build fails with the same errors, I guess I wrongly blamed Intellij. How can I tell why the dependencies are not being downloaded? They are sitting in my build.gradle in dependencies just as I showed. They are also present when running `gradle dependencies`. Under compile, default, runtime, testCompile and testRuntime, but not archives. Is that where the issue lies?

Comment: That's fine. However, `gradle dependencies` should show which dependencies can't be resolved. Did you declare a repository?

Comment: `gradle dependencies` doesn't say anything about dependencies not resolving. I will put its output in the original post.

Comment: It's not clear to me what's causing this. Perhaps try with some of the sample builds that ship with the `gradle-all` download.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html